# Php no me saca todos los datos que estan en la base de datos

Tags: php, poo, php7

no se porque mi `array` no contiene todos los datos.
Trato de **obtener todos los mensajes de un usuario**.
Obtengo los datos con esto:

```
public function verMensajesUsuario($usuario){
            $conexion = $this->c->conectar();

            $sql = "SELECT mensajes.id, titulo,contenido,createAt, usuario 
            FROM mensajes,usuarios  
            WHERE mensajes.creador = usuarios.id AND usuarios.usuario = '$usuario';";



            $result = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                return $result;
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }

        }
```

El cual yo se que datos me debe de traer de antemano ya que estoy **probando**.

Esta clase **maneja** los datos obtenidos por la anterior clase

```
<?php 
    if (!isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) {
        header('location: ../login.php');
    }

    require_once 'conexion.php';
    require_once 'controllers/mensaje.php';

    //esto no hace falta pero para que quede modularizado
    $usuario =$_SESSION['usuario'];


     $mensaje_controllers = new Mensaje();

     $result = $mensaje_controllers->verMensajesUsuario($usuario);
        var_dump($result);

$array_mensajes  = $result->fetch_array();

var_dump($array_mensajes);





 ?>
```

Deberia de obtener 6 mensajes de el usuario que tengo almacenado en la sesion `$_SESSION['usuario']`.

Haciendo un `var_dump()` de `$array_mensajes` yo espero obtener algo asi:

> mensajes  = 
>         mensaje 1 , sus datos 
>         mensaje 2 , sus datos 
>         mensaje 3 , sus datos 
>         mensaje 4 , sus datos 
>         mensaje 5 , sus datos 
>         mensaje 6 , sus datos

No es **JSON** ni nada solo es para que se entienda. Pero recibo :

```
  0 => string '6' (length=1)
  'id' => string '6' (length=1)
  1 => string 'titulo de jose ' (length=15)
  'titulo' => string 'titulo de jose ' (length=15)
  2 => string 'contenido de jose' (length=17)
  'contenido' => string 'contenido de jose' (length=17)
  3 => string '2019-04-20 17:47:40' (length=19)
  'createAt' => string '2019-04-20 17:47:40' (length=19)
  4 => string 'jose' (length=4)
  'usuario' => string 'jose' (length=4)
```

Es decir, se supone que hay **6 mensajes** de este **usuario** no se porque me devuelve eso, despues cuando lo intento **displayear** hace lo que le da la gana .

He intentado recorrerlo con `fetch_array()`, con `mysqli_fetch_array()` pero entre que algunos dan errores y otros no salen lo que espero entro en duda tambien sobre **como recorrerlo segun que consulta sea**

Comment: Probaste usar inner join en vez de producto cartesiano de tablas? Probaste la consulta en entorno como phpmyadmin? Developer oracle? Fijate capa es ese error

Comment: En mi `phpMyAdmin` me lo hace perfectamente

Comment: Me devuelve **todos los mensajes creados por el usuario**

Answer (score 0):

Cambia

```
$array_mensajes = $result->fetch_array();
var_dump($array_mensajes);
```

Por

```
$array_mensajes = $result->fetch_all();
var_dump($array_mensajes);
```

Esto debería devolver los mensajes que esperas.

Y si los quieres directamente en el Loop:

```
while($row = $consulta->fetch_all()) {
    var_dump($row);
}
```